# Not able to get the second value from the foreach in php

Tags: php, foreach

I am using foreach to loop through an array to display the data in a dropdown. In my db, I have 1 and 5 that have been registered. but when i run my page, it shows only the number 1. However if i print the array i can see it contains both 1 and 5.

```
if (is_array($time_of_app) || is_object($time_of_app))
{
foreach ($time_of_app as $key => $value) {

                if ($value == 1) {
                  $val1= '<option value="" disabled>09 00 - 10 00 [BOOKED]</option>';
                }else{
                    $val1 = '<option value="1">09 00 - 10 00</option>';  
                }
                if ($value == 2) {
                   $val2= '<option value="" disabled>10 00 - 11 00 [BOOKED]</option>';

                }else{
                     $val2 = '<option value="2">10 00 - 11 00</option>';
                }
              if ($value == 3) {
                $val3= '<option value="" disabled>11 00 - 12 00 [BOOKED]</option>';

                }else{
                  $val3 = '<option value="3">11 00 - 12 00</option>';
                }
                if ($value == 4) {
                  $val4= '<option value="" disabled>13 00 - 14 00 [BOOKED]</option>';

                }else{
                  $val4 = '<option value="4">13 00 - 14 00</option>';
                }
                if ($value == 5) {
                  $val5= '<option value="" disabled>14 00 - 15 00 [BOOKED]</option>';
                }else{
                   $val5 = '<option value="5">14 00 - 15 00</option>';
                }
                if ($value == 6) {
                  $val6= '<option value="" disabled>16 00 - 17 00 [BOOKED]</option>';

                }else{
                  $val6 = '<option value="6">16 00 - 17 00</option>';
                }
                if ($value == 7) {
                  $val7= '<option value="" disabled>17 00 - 18 00 [BOOKED]</option>';

                }else{
                 $val7 = '<option value="7">17 00 - 18 00</option>';
                }

                        }
}
```

[The screenshot of when the page is run.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HO2Ks.png)

P.S :I am not able to put the screenshot directly. The screenshot shows the dropdown and the values i get if i printr() my array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the values of each variables ($val1, $val2 etc.) outside the `foreach` loop, above it. You set the variables their respective `else'` values.

And inside the `foreach` just keep the `if statements` and remove all `elses`.

That should fix your issue.

Comment: Still not working. In fact I initialized the $val1,$val2 etc as    $val1 = ''; etc

Comment: Not like that as $val1 = '<option value="1">09 00 - 10 00</option>';

Comment: Follow my original instruction : You set the variables their respective else' values.

Comment: Remove all if statements that are like if($value !=){ in condition. Then post updated pastebin.

Comment: the updated link: https://pastebin.com/RRzCQQmh
I tried it with the updated code but it does not detect the second element from the array. But when i pritn it its there

Comment: I think if ($value == 3) { ... statement is not right. I think you need to update $var3 value there.

Comment: Should be okay now.

Comment: in ($value == 3) { ..  $val3= '<option value="3">11 00 - 12 00</option>';; <-- remove the extra ;

Comment: updated it but still not working. This is what i get when i print the array. In fact I have only 1 and 5 in my db, so Only the first and the fifth should be disabled. But what i'm getting is the first one only is disabled
Array ( [0] => 5 ) Array ( [0] => 1 )

Comment: This should fix it. Just inside the foreach loop add - $value = $value[0];

Comment: I added some comments to show where i think the problem is
https://pastebin.com/RQf7YW3h

Comment: Still not fixed? have you tested?

Comment: Not fixed yet. It still does not detect the second array which is '5'. i have a screenshot. 
https://ibb.co/ge8Cs7

Comment: hey its working. Can you tell me the line you modified? btw Thank you so much. been looking for the error since yesterday